# Problem when installing the cover package for golang

Tags: go, code-coverage

I have some code. 
But when 
I try run cover test and have response:

```
'go get -u github.com/gregoryv/uncover/...
go test -coverprofile /tmp/c.out
uncover /tmp/c.out'
```

I try install cover package:

```
go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover
```

but get error

```
package code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover: unrecognized import path "code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover" (parse https://code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags (meta tag github.com/golang/go did not match import path code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover))
```

System: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6):

The correct path is:

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover
```